# Why does the openSUSE live CD stop copying files to the system?

Tags: linux, installation

I was trying to install openSUSE11.4 using the Live CD. But when it started copying the root filesystem, it hung on 15% and waited forever. The CD stopped spinning too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance the CD contains an error that occurred while you were burning it. This could always happen, and if the installer fails to read data from the disc, it might just stop without any detailed error message. The CD stopping to spin would also be a hint that it can't read from the disc anymore.

Try to burn the CD again, but do so at a lower speed than usual, and **verify** the disc after burning. Any decent burn software should be able to do that.

Comment: Also, depending on the OS you were downloading and burning the files from, you could *verify* the .iso file by using the checksum provided at the openSUSE download page.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your suggestion. I have burned it on Fedora and using k3b ,which has inbuilt checksum checking facility.Let me try one more time.

Comment: Sure! Report back if it didn't work!